# How to read R32G32_SFLOAT image from gpu in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

I am able to dump stuff from R32G32B32A32 image for screenshot. I would like to read out a pixel from R32G32_SFLOAT image as well. But the result look weird.

[image]

below is my working image dump code(no validation error)

```
void DumpImageToFile(VkTool::VulkanDevice &device, VkQueue graphics_queue, VkTool::Wrapper::CommandBuffers &command_buffer, VkImage image, uint32_t width, uint32_t height, const char *filename)
{
    auto image_create_info = VkTool::Initializer::GenerateImageCreateInfo(VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D, VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, {width, height, 1},
        VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT, VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT);
    VkTool::Wrapper::Image staging_image(device, image_create_info, VK_MEMORY_HEAP_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT);
    auto buffer_create_info = VkTool::Initializer::GenerateBufferCreateInfo(width * height * 4, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT);
    VkTool::Wrapper::Buffer staging_buffer(device, buffer_create_info, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT);

    // Copy texture to buffer

    command_buffer.Begin();

    auto image_memory_barrier = VkTool::Initializer::GenerateImageMemoryBarrier(VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL,
    { VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 1, 0, 1 }, staging_image.Get());
    device.vkCmdPipelineBarrier(command_buffer.Get(), VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, 0
        , 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &image_memory_barrier);


    image_memory_barrier = VkTool::Initializer::GenerateImageMemoryBarrier(VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL,
    { VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 1, 0, 1 }, image);
    device.vkCmdPipelineBarrier(command_buffer.Get(), VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, 0
        , 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &image_memory_barrier);


    // Copy!!
    VkImageBlit region = {};
    region.srcSubresource = { VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 0, 1 };
    region.srcOffsets[0] = { 0, 0, 0 };
    region.srcOffsets[1] = { static_cast<int32_t>(width), static_cast<int32_t>(height), 1};
    region.dstSubresource = { VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 0, 1 };
    region.dstOffsets[0] = { 0, 0, 0 };
    region.dstOffsets[1] = { static_cast<int32_t>(width), static_cast<int32_t>(height), 1 };
    device.vkCmdBlitImage(command_buffer.Get(), image, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL, staging_image.Get(), VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, 1, &region, VK_FILTER_LINEAR);


    image_memory_barrier = VkTool::Initializer::GenerateImageMemoryBarrier(VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR,
    { VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 1, 0, 1 }, image);
    device.vkCmdPipelineBarrier(command_buffer.Get(), VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT, 0
        , 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &image_memory_barrier);

    image_memory_barrier = VkTool::Initializer::GenerateImageMemoryBarrier(VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL,
    { VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 1, 0, 1 }, staging_image.Get());
    device.vkCmdPipelineBarrier(command_buffer.Get(), VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, 0
        , 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &image_memory_barrier);

    auto buffer_image_copy = VkTool::Initializer::GenerateBufferImageCopy({ VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT , 0, 0, 1 }, { width, height, 1 });
    device.vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer(command_buffer.Get(), staging_image.Get(), VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL, staging_buffer.Get(), 1, &buffer_image_copy);

    command_buffer.End();

    std::vector<VkCommandBuffer> raw_command_buffers = command_buffer.GetAll();
    auto submit_info = VkTool::Initializer::GenerateSubmitInfo(raw_command_buffers);
    VkTool::Wrapper::Fence fence(device);
    device.vkQueueSubmit(graphics_queue, 1, &submit_info, fence.Get());
    fence.Wait();
    fence.Destroy();

    const uint8_t *mapped_address = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t *>(staging_buffer.MapMemory());
    lodepng::encode(filename, mapped_address, width, height);
    staging_buffer.UnmapMemory();

    staging_image.Destroy();
    staging_buffer.Destroy();
}
```

Sorry for the ugly self-made wrapper, there was no official wrapper. Basically, it creates a staging image and buffer. first copy from source image to staging image with vkCmdBlitImage. then use vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer and map the buffer to host memory. This method works on multiple gpus and it does not need to worry about padding.(I guess, correct me if I am wrong).

However, I have no luck to use this method to read R32G32_SFLOAT. at first I thought it was because of endianness until I dump the whole image out.

[image]

The image above is I directly convert R32G32_SFLOAT to R8G8B8A8_UNORM, I know it does not make sense. But without changing format, there's still a lot of "hole" in the image and values are deadly wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not really sure if it is THE problem, but if I understand your code, you want to put `image` into `filename`.
So you want to read from this image. However, you said that the old layout for this image (not the staging one) is UNDEFINED layout. The implementation is free to assume you do not care about data that are stored in it. Use the real layout instead (I think it is `COLOR_ATTACHMENT` or something like that).

Moreover, you are using one staging image and one staging buffer. I do not really understand why are you doing such a thing? Why not simply use `vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer` function with `image` to `staging_buffer`?

BTW, with Vulkan it is not because one code works on some GPUs that this code is correct.

Also, I think you must use a memory barrier after your transfer to the buffer that implies HOST_STAGE and HOST_READ. In the specification, it is write :

> Signaling a fence and waiting on the host does not guarantee that the results of memory accesses will be visible to the host, as the access scope of a memory dependency defined by a fence only includes device access. A memory barrier or other memory dependency must be used to guarantee this. See the description of host access types for more information.

Comment: Could you, please, comment on your last statement? I can't see how a well written and correctly synchronized code based over some set of available features can work on one GPU-driver pair that supports the feature list and not work on another GPU-driver pair that supports the same features.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding. I meant that some GPU requires more synchronization or proper layout transition than other GPU. For example, with NVIDIA you probably do not need to synchronize perfectly everything to make it work. AMD cards require more effort from the developer. However, I did not say that the code is correct. As I just said an incorrect code could work on NVIDIA but not on AMD, and it is the case for the OP. Its code works on some GPU but not on everyones ;)

Comment: The reason I use staging image is I would like to see what will happen when I use vkCmdBlitImage on different format of src and dst image. Yap It is color attachment. writing "undefined" really means I do not care about the format and synchronization at this moment. And I wish this function can be used for non color attachment image.

Comment: Ok but si you don't care about synchronization, format and data that are stored inside the image, do not ask why values are undefined... Or maybe I did not understand what you meant ^^

Comment: Like said in the specifications, UNDEFINED means you do not care about data. There is nothing to do about synchronisation or format ;). VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED does not support device access. This layout must only be used as the initialLayout member of VkImageCreateInfo or VkAttachmentDescription, or as the oldLayout in an image transition. When transitioning out of this layout, the contents of the memory are not guaranteed to be preserved.`

Comment: sorry, I just check the spec and I had misunderstanding on UNDEFINED_LAYOUT. by the time I wrote this program, I did not fully understand the barrier synchronization.

Comment: http://cpp-rendering.io/barriers-vulkan-not-difficult/ here is one link to help you to understand barriers

Comment: My wrong understanding on UNDEFINED is we could transform any format of image to desired format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155099/discussion-between-antoine-morrier-and-tim-hsu).

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code seems weird:

```
image_memory_barrier = VkTool::Initializer::GenerateImageMemoryBarrier(VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL, { VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 1, 0, 1 }, image);
device.vkCmdPipelineBarrier(command_buffer.Get(), VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, 0, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &image_memory_barrier);
```

This basically means that after the barrier your source image may not have any data. UNDEFINED value used as a source layout doesn't guarantee that the contents of an image are preserved.

Comment: [“you” versus “You” as polite form of writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/30185/25305)

Comment: @NicolBolas What's wrong with 'You' as polite form of writing? ;-)

Comment: Because, as shown by the link I showed you, English doesn't work that way.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know it is a link because it didn't look like one in my browser. But it's written there that such form is archaic. And as far as I know there is nothing wrong in using archaic forms. Besides is there any rule stating it's forbidden? Or is it  unusual? And what does it mean that "English doesn't work that way". As far as I know all languages are evolving, changing constantly. So if it's not forbidden or offensive, and I don't see how it can be misunderstood, there is nothing wrong in using such form. ;-)

Comment: That's like saying that RanDoM CaPiTaLiZaTiOn iS fInE, simply because there's no rule explicitly forbidding it. Capitalized words poke you in the eye; they're supposed to mean something. "You" is not important enough by English grammar to be capitalized, so doing so does nothing more than poke people in the eye to no effect. MuCh lIkE cApItAliZaTiOn oF LeTtErS, it doesn't improve readability.

Comment: Please, don't compare polite and archaic form with one capitalized first letter with totally unreadable text (maybe you should also change the size and font of every letter). If someone else you have a conversation with isn't important enough for you, it doesn't mean it's the same for everybody else. I was raised in a culture when one shows respect to others in writing by capitalizing You. And I don't see how it can harm anyone. And it's not unreadable as you're trying to suggest. I would prefer if you could correct my grammar, punctuation etc. so I could improve my English (english?? :-P).

Comment: "*I was raised in a culture when one shows respect to others in writing by capitalizing You.*" And I'm simply informing you that that's not how the *English* language works. Capitalizing "You" does not show respect to others in English. Whether it shows disrespect or not is a matter for the reader. But by and large, English readers do not see "You" and think "he's being formal and respectful".

Comment: Ok, I understand Your explanation but it doesn't mean I will stop writing like this. As I have written, all languages are alive, they are constantly changing. So treat it as some kind of an experiment, I'm checking if I can change the way people think about respectful forms of writing.